# How to minimize services in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-10.10

I am using ubuntu from last 6-7 months. I am having 512mb ram and a p4 processor with 1.73 Ghz processing speed. And being a programmer i have to work with eclipse and netbeans like ide's, and they sometimes hang.

So is there any option in ubuntu to stop the services running just like i do have in windows "msconfig" or mycomputer->manage, and where could i find the details about the services so that i should know what will be its effect if i stop this service. I am using ubuntu 10.10

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

See [this question on askubuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19320/whats-the-recommend-way-to-enable-disable-services/20351#20351) listing the standard ways to enable and disable services.

For what the different services actually do, good references are

- `man` pages
- Ubuntu [help pages](https://help.ubuntu.com/)
- general [Googling](http://www.google.no/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=what+is+tty1)
- [askubuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `top` program to find out which services are taking the most memory or CPU time.  You could then uninstall the packages that you don't need.  But note that normally services that are technically running but are not in use don't take CPU and can be swapped out, so you might not gain much in practice.  Also note that a fully-featured desktop environment such as GNOME starts a lot of little services that might stretch your resources.  Switching to something like LXDE could help.  But ultimately I suspect that Eclipse or Netbeans will be the biggest hog on the system, and you will struggle to get them working smoothly on that configuration.